# PostgreSQL join using LIKE/ILIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do an inexact join (I am not sure what the proper term is) where I could perform pattern matching. Basically, instead of doing a JOIN like this:

```
.... JOIN .... ON (t1.col = t2.col)
```

I would like to do do something like:

```
.... JOIN .... ON (t1.col ILIKE %(t2.col)% )
```

The second example is obviously not proper syntax. Is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
.... JOIN .... ON t1.col ILIKE '%' || t2.col || '%'
```

Please note that as written, AFAIK, PostgreSQL won't be able to use any indexes to speed up the join processing.

Answer (score 30):

An alternative way to join on “is the value of t2.col a substring of t1.col”:

```
... AS t1 JOIN ... AS t2 ON POSITION(t2.col IN t1.col)<>0
```

This still can't use indexes, but the advantage is you don't have to worry about `%` and `_` characters in `t2.col` which would otherwise start matching everything.

If you need case-insensitive matching like `ILIKE` and you're not using `citext` you'd need to `LOWER()` both columns before using `POSITION()`.

Comment: I thought this was a real clever solution. Just wanted to clarify that I picked the other answer because I thought it was more general and open-ended.

Comment: Thanks, It is working for me, After a lot of attempts,