# How do I JOIN 2 tables that have similar, but not exact same values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have 2 tables that I'm trying to join on the 'program' column (and others).
The issue is that the program names aren't exactly the same-- they're similar though.

Where one tables may have

```
program1
program2
program3
```

The other table may have:

```
xyz-program1-highlights
z-program1-extra
abc-program1
123-program2
3-program2
A-program3
```

or any variation thereof

Is there a way to basically do a LIKE command to find where table1 is LIKE table2 and join them?

I've tried

```
table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.program LIKE '%'||table2.program||'%'
```

(and some variations thereof) and it only matched one program (out of about 30)

In case this matters, table2 is a view with unioned views.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```sql
table1  join table2 on table1.program  LIKE '%' || table.program|| '%'
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772670/17766295) might help you

Comment: Unfortunately same issue-- only returning a similarity of 1 of the 30 programs :\