# Get rows where a field CONTAINS text from a column in a different table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, pattern-matching

I'm trying to search a field that contains information from another table. I've tried the following queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 
WHERE text_field LIKE '%'||(SELECT other_text FROM table_2)||'%';
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 
WHERE text_field ~* '(SELECT other_text FROM table_2)';
```

Unfortunately, I get:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Example tables:

`table_1`

| id | timestamp | text_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-06-01 17:40:00 | Two Transactions completed in 12 seconds |
| 101 | 2022-06-01 17:42:42 | One Transaction completed in 5 seconds |
| 102 | 2022-06-02 03:24:23 | 15 Records created and 4 deleted in 94 seconds |

`table_2`

| id | other_text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 94 |
| 2 | 12 |

And I want to query table_1 based on text_field containing either 12 or 94, which would give me this return:

| id | timestamp | text_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-06-01 17:40:00 | 2 Transactions completed in 12 seconds |
| 102 | 2022-06-02 03:24:23 | 15 Records created and 4 deleted in 94 seconds |

I've looked at multiple suggestions but they all center around a JOIN, but my `text_field` won't ever EQUAL my `other_text` field.
I've looked at arrays, but each entry in `table_2` is distinct, not a comma-delimited list.  Each `text_field` entry has the potential to be a varying length as indicated in my example, so I can't just select the 6th 'space-delimited' field in `text_field`; I have to do some version of "contains" or "like".

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can join on inequalities

Comment: I was thinking something like `join table_2 t2 on t1.text_field like '%' || t2.other_text || '%'` and this answer suggests it would work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772670/2568649

Comment: Can you give a little more detail?  Example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining tables like the currently accepted answer suggests, is typically not what you want. The question is not entirely clear there.

If `other_text` contains *4*, *9*, *15*, and *94*, your row with *"15 Records created and 4 deleted in 94 seconds"* would be listed in the result four times. Use [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) instead to get distinct result rows:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table_1 t1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t1.text_field ~ t2.other_text)
ORDER  BY t1.id;  -- optional
```

With more than a few duplicate matches, it's faster, too.

Related:

- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)

If `other_text` can contain special characters for `LIKE` or the regexp match `~` (whichever you use) you may want to escape them:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

Aside: yes, that's a "join" too:

```
SELECT * FROM a,b WHERE a.x LIKE b.y;
```

It's the less readable twin of:

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.x LIKE b.y;
```

See:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167217/3684)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html)(Common Table Expression).

```
WITH ot as(
   SELECT other_text FROM table_2)
SELECT * 
FROM ot, table_1 
WHERE text_field LIKE '%'|| ot.other_text||'%';
```

To be complete I should mention you can shorten this to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2, table_1 
WHERE text_field LIKE '%'|| table2.other_text||'%';
```

**UPDATE**

I prefer the first form as it makes it clearer to me what is going on.

Comment: Add **UPDATE** with alternate query.